# Products of Orthogonal Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $a,b,c$ be orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then is $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k}b_{k}c_{k} = 0$?

I tried two examples and it was true, but I don't immediately see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the only conditions you have are $\sum_ka_kb_k=0$ etc. [This code](https://repl.it/repls/SolidConsciousDevelopments) finds a random $n=3$ example where $\sum_ka_kb_kc_k\ne0$.

Comment: I guess the simple examples I tried were misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample:

$$a = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\end{pmatrix},~~b = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\end{pmatrix},~~ c = \begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\\\frac{-2}{\sqrt 6}\end{pmatrix}.~~$$

Then

$$\sum_k a_kb_kc_k = \frac{2\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 6}{18} \neq 0.$$

Rational counterexample:

$$a = \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\-2\end{pmatrix},~~b = \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{pmatrix},~~c = \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix}-2\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$

In this case, $$\sum_k a_kb_kc_k = \frac{-4}{27} \neq 0.$$